# How to mock nested properties with PropertyMock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to mock a property of a property from the return value of a library function `mlflow.get_run(run_id).data.metrics`. I know how to mock a single layer like this:

```
m = mock.MagicMock(spec_set=mlflow.get_run)
type(m).metrics = mock.PropertyMock(side_effect=[1, 2])
print(m.metrics)
print(m.metrics)

###output
1
2
```

If I mock the nested property though I got error "MagicMock has no attribute 'data'"

```
type(m).data.metrics = mock.PropertyMock(side_effect=[1, 2])
```

What is the correct way to mock nested properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to basically repeat what you did for `m` and `data`. Set the `return_value` of the `data` property to another `MagickMock` and then set its type to `PropertyMock`.

```py
from unittest import mock

m = mock.MagicMock(spec_set=mlflow.get_run)
type(m).data = mock.PropertyMock(return_value=mock.MagicMock())
type(type(m).data).metrics = mock.PropertyMock(side_effect=[1, 2])

print(m.data.metrics)
# 1
print(m.data.metrics)
# 2
```

Comment: Did it print out 1 and 2 on your end? I ran this code and it printed out two `MagicMock` objects. `<MagicMock name='mock.metrics' id='1899336580544'>
<MagicMock name='mock.metrics' id='1899336580544'>`

Comment: Hi @ddd, I see I had a typo (`type(type(m).data).metric` instead of `metrics`). Now it works for me. Does it work for you?